# List of listings name in header

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, header-footer

I have a two-sided `book` document and want to format the header such that the chapter name is on the outer part. Everything works fine, but one thing annoys me. I have some source code listings (`listings` package) and pseudo codes (`algorithmicx` package). All the chapter names are given "normally" but the list of listings (named "Listings") and list of algorithms are put in all-caps in the header.

I probably need to override some settings for these packages, but I cannot find out which. How can I change the way "Listings" and "List of Algorithms" is put by the `\chaptermark` command (if that's the correct one)?

Here is a small example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}

\fancypagestyle{fancyplain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{\fancyplain}{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{thesection\ #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\lhead}[1]{\fancyhead[OL,ER]{\fancyplain{}\chaptermark{#1}}}
\fancyhead[OR,EL]{\fancyplain{}\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My listing},label=lst:my_listing,language=C++]
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
\end{lstlisting}
\cleardoublepage

\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\lstlistoflistings` uses `\tableofcontents`, which explicitly uses `\MakeUppercase` --> that's the reason!

Comment: Okay, can I disable the \MakeUppercase? In your solution below I would have to override all other commands like `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to remove or replace `\tableofcontents` by a modified version which does not have `\MakeUppercase\contentsname`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xpatch}



\makeatletter

\newcommand{\othertableofcontents}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
          \contentsname}{\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\makeatother

\xpatchcmd{\lstlistoflistings}{%\
  \tableofcontents}{%
  \othertableofcontents}{}{}

%\lst@UserCommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
%    \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
%    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
%    \othertableofcontents \egroup}

\fancypagestyle{fancyplain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{\fancyplain}{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{thesection\ #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\lhead}[1]{\fancyhead[OL,ER]{\fancyplain{}\chaptermark{#1}}}
\fancyhead[OR,EL]{\fancyplain{}\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My listing},label=lst:my_listing,language=C++]
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
\end{lstlisting}
\cleardoublepage

\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Since the O.P. requested to have non upper case headings for `ToC`, `LoT` etc, I suggest to use `\cftmarkX` from the `tocloft` package.

I've done this and redefined the relevant commands using `\markboth{...}{...}` for both margins of the page -- this is alright, since the O.P. does a redefinition later on anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\renewcommand{\cftmarktoc}{\markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}}
\renewcommand{\cftmarklof}{\markboth{\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}}
\renewcommand{\cftmarklot}{\markboth{\listtablename}{\listtablename}}


\fancypagestyle{fancyplain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{\fancyplain}{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{thesection\ #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\lhead}[1]{\fancyhead[OL,ER]{\fancyplain{}\chaptermark{#1}}}
\fancyhead[OR,EL]{\fancyplain{}\thepage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\chapter{My chapter}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My listing},label=lst:my_listing,language=C++]
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
\end{lstlisting}
\cleardoublepage

\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works. Can I do this "globally", i.e. for all possible list types that use `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: @tickferno: Of course. I will update, for `\tableofcontents` this is easy.

Comment: @tickferno: See the update, please

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm new here. Should be done now

Comment: @tickferno: Thanks. This is crucial to `close` the question as being successfully answered